# how do add a negative RewriteCond condition?

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need an extra condition to the following rewrite rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
```

if the url has a "/eng/" in it, than i dont want this rewrite to happen? How can I add this kind of condition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^((?!eng/).+?)/?$ $1.php [L,NC]
```

OR else:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule !^eng/ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L,NC]
```